# PHP GET Request WIth Authorization works in Postman but not in CURL

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to authenticate with Envato OAuth. I successfully get the access token but when I try to make a GET request using the access token but it given me Unauthorized message. Here is my PHP code.

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_GET['token'])){
    echo "<h2>!!! Oops:( </h2>";
    exit();
}
$token = $_GET['token'];
$apiUrl = 'https://api.envato.com/v3/market/buyer/purchases?page=1';

$headers = array(
    'Authorization'    => 'Bearer '.$token,
);
echo $headers;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

// Timeout in seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

// Check if any error occurred
print_r($result);
if(empty($result))
{ 
    echo '<br>Error<br>';
}else{
    echo "<br><br>";
    $json = json_decode($result, true);
}

?>
```

This code gives

> Array{"message":"Unauthorized"}

But when i try to request the same page in postman, it returns the data successfully. I tried to find a solution here but none of them helped.

[image: Postman Request Sample]

Comment: the headers should be like this $headers = array(
    'Authorization: Bearer '.$token
);

Comment: Wow. You just made my day. Working like charm. Thanks.